# Facebook Login Error 191 when use IIS Virtual Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, iis

I already look other reference article but still can't solve my problem

I own a site named https://shop.yourdomain.com/
Because all my users use Android in App view to browse my site, I manually build a facebook login flow and It works perfectly.
(ref:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)

My problem is below:
I build another website and use IIS virtual directory and use it as a application and URL is 
https://shop.yourdomain.com/second-site/

but this time when I use facebook login it will return info below.

API Error Code: 191
API Type OAuthException: OAuthException
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Already Set Facebook Login APP
1.Setting -> Basic -> Domain add https://shop.yourdomain.com/
2.Facebook login -> Setting -> Valid OAuth Redirect URI add https://shop.yourdomain.com/
3.Redirect Strict Mode -> off

**Ever Tried**
1.I tried adding https://shop.yourdomain.com/second-site/ to Facebook login -> Setting -> Valid OAuth Redirect URI, but it still didn't work.

2.When I develop this website on my own computer, I use http://localhost:port/ and add http://localhost:port on facebook application setting, and login flow is work.

Has anyone ever encountered a problem of that kind? Please help me. Thank you so much.

**Logic Flow Detail is below:**

1.After user click 'login' button, then Javascript redirect to Facebook Oauth
`location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth
?client_id=XXX
&redirect_uri=https://shop.yourdomain.com/second-site/login/facebooklogin/
&state=parameters`

2.(Redirect to Facebook Domain)User Login in Facebook or User auth Facebook for my website
3.Facebook HttpGet Back To my WebSite

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FacebookLogin(string code, string error, string state)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string facebookUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/";
        string facebookMethod = "v2.12/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXX
        &redirect_uri=https://shop.yourdomain.com/second-site/login/facebooklogin/
        &client_secret=OOO&code=code;

        var facebookToken = client.GetAsync(facebookUrl + facebookMethod).Result;
        string facebookTokenString = facebookToken.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        JObject facebookTokenResult = JObject.Parse(facebookTokenString);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
}
```

4. facebookTokenResult is below

```
{
    "error":{
       "message":"Can't Load this website : this website is not include in application domain. If you want to load this website, please add all domain and subdomain in 'application domain'(I translate it in English)",
       "type":"OAuthException",
       "code":191,
       "fbtrace_id":"XXXOOO"
    }
}
```

Comment: "use IIS virtual host". IIS does not have the virtual host concept. Do you mean virtual directory or application? You should also dig into the actual HTTP request sent to Facebook in your browser's developer tools and paste the necessary info as part of the question.

Comment: @LexLi Thank for your advice, I modify it to virtual directory and I will add more info about the http request.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer and is not about the any facebook setting.
The problem is the http and https and I only set facebook allow https.
I make a mistake that I put only http url in c# code and that is why facebook always tell me that domain is not allowed.